# What does "self-contained" mean?

Tags: html, terminology, figure, self-contained

I’ve read the [definition of figure](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/figure.html):

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is ***self-contained***, that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning.

But I still don’t understand the “self-contained” part. Could anyone clarify it please?

Comment: Does the [tag description of “self-contained”](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/self-contained/info) help? _“Self-contained in programming can refer to a script, program or a library that is completely independent and contains everything necessary within its code.”_ It’s not clear what you don’t understand about it. What do you think it means?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for the definition of a word and is not about programming as defined by the scope of the Help Center.

Comment: Well I thought that self contained could have a special meaning, because as far as I understand, a tag couldn't stand completely alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element):

> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a
>   caption, that is self-contained (like a complete sentence) and is
>   typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of the
>   document.
>
> Self-contained in this context does not necessarily mean independent.
>   For example, each sentence in a paragraph is self-contained; an image
>   that is part of a sentence would be inappropriate for figure, but an
>   entire sentence made of images would be fitting.
>
> The element can thus be used to annotate illustrations, diagrams,
>   photos, code listings, etc.